# Is there a way to omit layout_height in order to have two views have identical heights?

Tags: android, xml

I wish to accomplish having the height of a view conform the the height of the another view, in other words have them exactly the same. I've tried using constraintview, but this requires omitting layout_height in order for it to work.

The following gives me a crash and requires layout_height:

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/img"
            android:id="@+id/bg"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dateText" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Test text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textColor="@color/bluetext"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bg"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/leftGuideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bg"/>
```

Is there a simple way to make the heights exactly the same without using a fixed height for both views?

Comment: are you saying you were not able to achieve above with constraint layout??

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work if I set the textview's height to wrap_content.

Comment: Okay, on second thought, it wraps to the content, and centers it; however the fact still stands that the height isn't the exact same.

Comment: if you are planning on having your image view and text view the same height, you can have one of it constrained to its parent or fixed size. Then have your other view constrained to the first one. make sure to have your height `match_constraint` and have 0 margin for the second view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:layout_height="0dp"` (a.k.a., "match constraint"), to say that you want the height to be determined by the top and bottom constraints that you have set up.

Note that you may need to adjust the `android:gravity` attribute of your `TextView` to your liking. The `TextView` itself will take up the desired height, but the *text* may be smaller (or larger, if it has lots of lines).